# Surface integral of a partially constant Dirac delta

Tags: coordinate-systems, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, spherical-coordinates, surface-integrals

I am trying to integrate the product of a function and a partially constant delta function over a sphere of constant radius $r$.

The integral is of the form

$$\int^{2\pi}_0 \int^{\pi}_0 f(\mathbf{r})\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0) \sin\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta \,\mathrm{d}\phi.  $$

I know that this integral is very simple when the delta function is fully three-dimensional, such as $$\delta^3(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r}_0)=\delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)\delta(z-z_0),$$ but what I have here is something a bit different. Does anyone have anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: should you have also integral in $r$ for spherical coordinates?

Comment: no, it's a surface integral over the sphere of constant radius $r$, so there is no integration on $\,\mathrm{d}r$.

Comment: if $r$ is constant $f(r)$ is constant should it be $f(r_0)$?

Comment: it's not $f(r)$ but rather $f(\mathbf{r})$. That is, the function $f$ takes as an argument the vector $\mathbf{r}$, not just the distance from the origin $r$

Comment: Moreover, $r_0$ is not defined in the context of the problem, but only $x_0$ and $y_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we give a rough sketch, and leave it to the reader to iron out various technical issues.

1. Define the [spherical coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) $(r,\theta,\phi)$ as
   $$\begin{align} x~=~&r\xi, \qquad \xi~=~\sin\theta\cos\phi, \cr y~=~&r\eta, \qquad \eta~=~\sin\theta\sin\phi, \cr z~=~&r\cos\theta. \end{align} \tag{1} $$
2. Define reflection
   $$\sigma: (x,y,z)\mapsto (x,y,-z)\tag{2}$$
   in the $(x,y)$-plane.
3. Define function
   $$g({\bf r})~:=~f({\bf r})+f\circ\sigma({\bf r}), \qquad {\bf r}~=~(x,y,z).\tag{3}$$
4. Define function
   $$h({\bf r})~:=~\frac{g({\bf r})}{rz}.\tag{4}$$
5. Define unit disk
   $$  D~:=~\{(\xi,\eta)\in\mathbb{R}^2 \mid \xi^2+\eta^2~<~1\}. \tag{5}$$
6. OP's integral then reads
   $$\begin{align}  I:~=~& \int_0^{2\pi}\!d\phi~\int_0^{\pi}\!d\theta~\sin\theta ~f({\bf r}) \delta(x-x_0)\delta(y-y_0)\cr
   ~=~&\int_0^{2\pi}\!d\phi~\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\!d\theta~\sin\theta\cos\theta ~h({\bf r})\delta\left(\xi-\frac{x_0}{r}\right)\delta\left(\eta-\frac{x_0}{r}\right)\cr
   ~=~&\iint_D \!d\xi~d\eta ~h({\bf r})\delta\left(\xi-\frac{x_0}{r}\right)\delta\left(\eta-\frac{x_0}{r}\right)\cr
   ~=~&\left\{\begin{array}{ccc} h\left(x_0, y_0, \sqrt{r^2-x_0^2-y_0^2}\right) &{\rm for}& x_0^2+y_0^2<r^2, \cr
   \frac{1}{2}h(x_0, y_0, 0) &{\rm for}& x_0^2+y_0^2=r^2, \cr 
   0 &{\rm for}& x_0^2+y_0^2>r^2.
   \end{array}\right. \end{align}\tag{6}$$

Comment: Wow. Thank you. Tremendously.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not great with proper mathematics notations. The open circle in equation 5: does this indicate applying the reflection operation to the argument of the function $f(\mathbf{r})$?

Comment: Also, it appears you've defined $\eta$ and $\xi$ identically. I think $\eta = \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi}$?

Comment: Ups. Yes. Corrected. And yes: $f\circ\sigma({\bf r})=f(\sigma({\bf r}))$.

Comment: Another point: if $h(\mathbf{r})=g(\mathbf{r})/r z$, what is the value of the integral when $x_0^2+y_0^2 = r^2 $, as in this case $z=0$ and thus $h(x_0,y_0,0)=g(x_0,y_0,0)/0$. Intuition would tell me it's actually a delta function, that is $h(x_0,y_0,0)=\frac{\delta(0) g(x_0,y_0,0)}{2r^2}$

Comment: 1. Well, that was one of the reasons to put the disclaimer in the first line of the answer :) Note however that the fraction $h$ could be extended to a well-defined regular function if the numerator $f$ has a matching zero at $z=0$. 2. Finally, your last intuitive comment about a delta function seems to make no mathematical sense.

Comment: :) thanks again! Yes, I know it makes no mathematical sense, but I have two ways of approaching the physics of the problem. One route does not involve this specific integration. If I model this alternative route using the integration based approach detailed here, treating these $z=0$ points as delta functions, the results correspond perfectly (if that makes any sense).

I should add that in the specific case I'm looking at, $f$ does not have a matching zero at $z=0$.